# PHP empty string check with SimpleXMLElement casted to string and then to boolean

Tags: php, string, soap, casting

I have this kind of situation:

```
$myString = '';
$client = new SoapClient($this->getWsdl());
$objectresult = $client->__soapCall("method", array(
            $this->getParams()
        ));
$res = new SimpleXMLElement($objectresult->result);
$myString = (string) $res->Description;
```

Let's say that $myString is "apparently" an empty string.

Is there any situation (maybe PHP version?) in which you can obtain different results doing that?

```
if(! $myString){} // #1

if($myString == ""){} // #2
```

On a machine with PHP 5.3.3, #1 is false and #2 is true I don't know why...

This thing is so odd that makes me crazy.

Thank you in advance.